# SetEnvIfNoCase doesn't work when user ip is IPv6

Tags: .htaccess, setenvif

i blocked some bots in my htaccess file

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "sitechecker.pro" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "seostar" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SiteCheckerBotCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "scan.lol" bad_bot

<Limit GET POST HEAD DELETE>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all 

  Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

but when their ip is IPv6 : exemple  : `2a00:8a60:1014:88::15`

they can access my website even if they are blocked
please any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? It's unlikely that `SetEnvIfNoCase` "doesn't work" per se, it's more likely that the server is (erroneously) configured differently when accessed using IPv6, such that `AllowOverride` is restricted or not enabled at all?

Comment: i have no clue about all this 